# Find Rank of element in unsorted array in complexity:O(lg n).Any other better approach than this?

Tags: algorithm, rank

given numbers in an unsorted way say X:{4,2,5,1,8,2,7}

How do you find rank of number??

Eg: Rank of 4:4
: Rank of 5:5

Complexity has to be O(lg n).

It can be done in complexity of O(lg n) with the help of Red Black Trees and Augmented Data structure approach(one of the fascinating stuff nowadays).
lets make use of order statistic tree[Order Statistic Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree)

```
Algorithm:
RANK(T,x)

//T: order-statistic tree, x: node(to find rank of this node)
r = x.left.size + 1
y=x
While y != T.root
    if y==y.p.right
        r= + y.p.left.size + 1
    y=y.p
Return r;
```

any help is appreciated.

are there any better approach than this??

Comment: What's a rank of a number in an array (permutation?)? I can't find any definition that fits these data types, let alone the example

Comment: The only function I can think of that corresponds to your data is `O(1)` to compute, not `O(n)`

Comment: downvoters:please review my solution.

Comment: any feedback is appreciated as i am new to this.

Comment: You should provide a link r reference for definition of rank of number in unordered set.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri : rank is the position of the element when it is sorted.

Comment: @MitchWheat:please review my solution.

Comment: @robert: no its not.I forgot to post my solution.Now its posted.please review it

Comment: @JanDvorak:rank is the position of the element when it is sorted.say a[]={6,8,3,4,2,1}.Rank of 4 is 4,rank of 6 is 5,rank of 8 is 6.Please review my solution.Feedback appreciated!!

Comment: @GauravPatil then it's impossible to find out below O(n), unless the array is a permutation, then it's trivial.

Comment: @GauravPatil what is `T`? An arbitrary tree does not have any special properties that you can use. If you can prepare an arbitrary data structure, then it's trivial in `O(lg n)` by presorting (`O(n lg n)`) and binary search.

Comment: Umm... _both_ lookup operations listed on wikipedia on the order-statistic tree (rank(x) and elem_at(i)) are trivial in plain ordered arrays. Order-statistic tree doesn't provide any benefit to either. What it does is that it makes insertion faster, and you don't need insertion here.

Answer (score 2):

> Given numbers in an unsorted way, say `X:{4,2,5,1,8,2,7}`
>
> How do you find rank of number?
>
> Rank is the position of the element when it is sorted.
>
> Complexity has to be O(lg n).

That's impossible. You have to look at each element at least once. Thus, you can't get better than `O(n)`, and it's trivial in O(n):

- set `found` to `false`
- set `smaller` to 0
- for each number in `array`

  - if the number is smaller than `needle`

    - increment the smaller counter
  - if the number is equal to the `needle`

    - set `found` to `true`
- if `found`, return `smaller+1`, else return error

---

> It can be done in complexity of O(lg n) with the help of Red Black Trees and Augmented Data structure approach(one of the fascinating stuff nowadays). Let's make use of order statistic tree

The problem is you *don't* have an order-statistic tree, and you don't have the time to build one. Building an order-statistic tree takes more than `O(lg n)` time*.

---

But let's say you have the time to build an order-statistic tree. Since extracting the sorted list of nodes in a binary search tree takes linear time, building an order-statistic tree cannot be faster than sorting an array directly.

So, let's sort the array directly. Then, finding the rank of an element is equivalent to finding the element in a sorted array. This is a well known task that can be solved in `O(lg n)` via binary search (repeatedly split the array in half until you find the element). It turns out that the order-statistic tree does not, quite, help. In fact, you can imagine the binary search as a lookup in an order-statistic tree (except the tree doesn't actually exist).

---

If `x` could change at runtime, then order-statistic trees do help. Then, element removal/addition takes `Th(lg n)` (worst-case) time, while it takes `Th(n)`* (average-case) in an ordinary sorted array because you need shift the elements around. With `x` immutable, order-statistic trees don't speed up anything over plain arrays.

---

* Technically, `O(lg n)` is a set of functions that grow asymptotically no more than `lg n`. When I say "more than `O(lg n)`", the correct interpretation is "more than every function in `O(lg n)`. Incidentally, this is equivalent to saying the run time is `omega(lg n)` (note the omega is lowercase).

`Th(lg n)` is the set of functions that are asymptotically equal to `lg n`, up to a constant. Expressing the same using O(lg n) and english while staying technically correct would be awkward.